# How to write JUNIT test cases for Code given

Tags: java, junit, testcase

I am totally confused how to write test case for for 1st condition that is `this==tgp`, and same mentioned below:

```
public boolean equals(Object tjp) {
    if (this == tjp) {
        return true;
    }
    if (tjp == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != tjp.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Fun other = (Fun) tjp;
    if (getId() == null) {
        if (other.getId() != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!getId().equals(other.getId())) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: assertTrue(testObject.equals(testObject));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood what you want you could test it using mocks ([Mockito](http://mockito.org) for example) :

- Test ok if == : `assertTrue(myObj.equals(myObj));`
- Test false if null : `assertFalse(myObj.equals(null));`
- Verify that given a not null mock, its getClass() method is called.

That way you control that you pass by the correct ways (white box testing)

Answer (score 0):

This is an `equals()` method of a `Java` class. I don't think this method testing is necessary.

If you really want to check this you can use  `assertTrue(testObject.equals(testObject));`